# Can't change themes in Cinnamon session after an update - Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: themes, cinnamon, nemo

I was happily using Cinnamon until today, when Ubuntu suggested I update it. I do admit I didn't read what the update was about, and just let it run.

Problem is that now after a reboot, the Cinnamon session won't use the theme I was already using and it won't let me change to anything else than the standard theme, including Icons, GTK and window themes.

What bothers me is that if I log with a Gnome Fallback session or a Unity Session, I can change back to the theme I was using. As soon as I go back to Cinnamon though I'm stuck with the standard one. Trying to change the theme with Gnome Tweak Tool does absolutely nothing.

Also, I get an error message that informs that nemo has crashed with SIGABRT in raise ().

I tried removing (sudo apt-get --purge autoremove cinnamon) and reinstaling it, but nothing changed.

What can I do to go back to my old looks?

Comment: weird, cinnamon 2.0.2 seems to cause many problems with ubuntu. Maybe you can try installing CUbuntu http://cubuntu.fr/?q=node/7

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I can give you some information.

You can't go back to your old looks, for now. To get back your theme, you'll have to purge any package in relation to nemo or cinnamon. So you'll have to use nautilus, or any file manager, waiting for cinnamon to fix the issue.